# best way to store DAWG(Directed Acyclic Word-Graph) and findout if word exist

Tags: java, performance, dawg

so i wrote a code to construct a dawg. i want to findout if a word exist in a language or not? after a lot of search i findout best way is to use dawg. [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s06/www/lectures/scrabble.pdf)

```
public class DawgNode
{
    public DawgNode(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool Final { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<char, DawgNode> Edges { get; set; } = new Dictionary<char, DawgNode>();

    public string Str()
    {
        var arr = new List<string>();
        if (Final) arr.Add("1");
        else arr.Add("0");
        foreach (var e in Edges)
        {
            arr.Add(e.Key.ToString());
            arr.Add(e.Value.Id.ToString());
        }
        return string.Join("-", arr);
    }
}
```

whats the best way to look up if a word exist. consider i want to implement scrabble game in a react native app.
i understand number of nodes can be minimized, but what's the trick.
1- saving nodes and edges in seperated files? how?
2- convert every time a big text into a dawg and search in it?
please help

Comment: I would have a Set of words and use `if (words.contains(word))`

Comment: there would be no problem if your set have 100 thousands of words? because the language i work on it have even more words?

Comment: HashSet works well up to about one billion elements. After that, it doesn't scale so well due to the limited 32-bit hashCode() and the size of the underlying array. It is builtin and well tested over the last 20 years ;)